# matplotlib pcolor with modified axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Goal: I want to modify the axis of the pcolor plot in such a way that the pcolor plot is not changed and not shifted, only the axis!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
phi = np.random.random([20,10])
xticks = range(10)
yticks = range(10)
ax.pcolor(phi,norm=LogNorm(vmin=10E-3, vmax=10E3))
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_yticks(yticks)
fig.show()
```

[failed plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUnJH.png)

Comment: Is this meant to be a runnable sample? It's not doing much for me.